# Exclamation mark in front of await

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

One case I've looked up where this is used is Navigator with WillPopScope as the parent as mentioned in the comment of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56893728/13743674) answer.

To put my question concretely, the following code should pop from the nested navigator but instead the app exits when the back button is pressed on android.

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(title: 'Navigation Basics', home: PearlScreen()));
}


class PearlScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const PearlScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PearlScreen> createState() => _PearlScreenState();
}

class _PearlScreenState extends State<PearlScreen> {
  final _navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async => await _navigatorKey.currentState!.maybePop(),
      child: Navigator(
        key: _navigatorKey,
        onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
          Widget screen;
          switch (settings.name) {
            case '/':
              screen = const HomeScreen();
              break;
            case '/quiz':
              screen = const QuizScreen();
              break;
            default:
              throw "Invalid route in Pearl: ${settings.name}";
          }
          return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => Material(child: screen),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But as soon as I change it to `onWillPop: () async => !await _navigatorKey.currentState!.maybePop()`, it works correctly and pops from the nested navigator instead of exiting the app.

What is the significance of `!await`?

Comment: A prefix "!" is the boolean "not" operator.  True becomes false, and false becomes true.